# cannot import module installed by easy_install

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I have installed seaborn library using easy_install and could confirm that it is installed checking pip list.
However, when I try to import seaborn library from ipython notebook, I get following error.

> ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'

Usually, I use pip install and this procedure works without problem. However, I am trying to use easy_install because pip install does not work in my office.
Does anyone know why this is happening and give me advice?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you let me know of your Python version?

Comment: My python version is  Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)